# What is the watching order for The X-Files?

Tags: the-x-files, suggested-order

About two weeks ago, I had never seen an episode of *The X-Files*.

I am in the process of watching *The X-Files* back to back, having never seen them before. I am about half way through season 2.

Some guys at work have told me I need to watch the movie at the right time or it will ruin the entire thing, but they can't remember when.

So, when should I watch the first, and by extension any other *X-Files* movies?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_X-Files_episodes#The_X-Files:_Fight_the_Future_.281998.29) has the answer.

Comment: I was asking when was best to watch the movie(s), not when it/they were made!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference.  The link lays out that `The film takes place between seasons 5 and 6` which was also when it was released.  That's the point when you should watch it.

Comment: OK, I was given the impression that this may not be the case, thanks!

Comment: And the second X-Files movie you should never watch, unless you want to run the MSR

Comment: @CamelBlues What does "run the MSR" mean?

Comment: @pacoverflow sorry, I meant "ruin", not run. MSR stands for Mulder-Scully relationship

Comment: Finish season 2, then leave the rest of it well alone.

Answer (score 7):

X-Files afficianado [Robert Frost](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-right-way-to-watch-all-the-X-Files-franchise-in-order-of-the-story) came up with the following watch order for the series and its various spin-offs and crossovers.

> [image: visual watch order for x-files, as detailed below]

> Watch The *[X-Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files)*, seasons 1 – 5.
>
> The first X-Files movie, simply titled *X-Files*, but now often referred
> to as *[X-Files: Fight the Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files_(film))*, takes place in-between seasons 5 and
> 6.
>
> Watch season 6.
>
> Start Season 7. Season 7 features an episode titled “*Millennium*”. It
> is episode 4 of the season. The episode is intended to serve as a
> conclusion to the series *Millennium*. You do not need to watch the
> series *Millennium* to watch episode 4, but if you want to watch
> *Millennium*, watch it between episodes 3 and 4 of *X-Files* season 7.
>
> Complete Season 7. Watch Season 8.
>
> Start Season 9. Episode 15 of season 9 is called “Jump the Shark”.
> This episode serves as an end to the story of *The Lone Gunmen*. If you
> want to watch the one season of the spin-off *The Lone Gunmen*, watch it
> before episode 15. Then complete Season 9. Watch the second film,
> titled *[X-Files: I Want to Believe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files:_I_Want_to_Believe)*. The ending of this film pretty much
> leaves the characters in the state we find them in the new miniseries.
>
> Watch the new [*X-Files* (2016)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files_(season_10)) [Season 10] 6 episode miniseries.

The show continued into a [Season 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files_(season_11)) which should obviously be watched after the previous season.

---

Additionally, there were several [comicbook spinoffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files#Comic_books), notably a "[Season 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files_Season_11_(comics))" comic serial, executive-produced by X-Files showrunner Chris Carter. This should obviously be read after the finale of Season 11 as it contains (some) spoilers and functions as an alternate ending to the show.